# How do I accurately switch lanes on notepad or EmEditor?

Tags: swap

So basically i have these lanes:

```
email:email123
email112:email12
email1:email
```

and i want them to get switched like this:

```
email123:email
email12:email112
email:email1
```

any way to do it?

notepad++ , em editor, excel?

Comment: so you want a programatical way to Switch left and right side of `:` separated values? if it's all the same to you: copy to Excel, text to column with `:` as separator, Switch columns, in C1 `=A1&":"&B1`, C should hold the values you wnated

Comment: i appreciate the answer but im not an excel fan, i barely work on it, would like an answer on how to do it on notepad++ or EmEditor